# Django can't display image

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show an image but every time image is broken:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "media/"
```

**models.py**

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='article_image/')
```

**Template (presenter.html)**

```
<img src="{{ art.image.path }}">
```

The path looks like this `/home/mikemoix/IdeaProjects/vlad/media/article_image/aptitude_test1.gif`

What can I do?

Comment: There are a couple things that might be the problem.  First, to get the **link** version you need to use `{{art.image.ur}]`, which will give you the link version, rather than `{{art.image.path}}`, which gives you the file system path.  You also might need to change your `MEDIA_ROOT` to "/media/" -- but that would depend on what your file structure actually looks like

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to link to an image is:

```
<img src="{{ art.image.url }}">
```

An `ImageField` is essentially stored as a `FieldFile`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) for details.

Comment: Its not work. Should i change MEDIA_ROOT or add MEDIA_URL?
**log**:
......
 "GET /article/getarticles/0/media/article_image/aptitude_test1.gif HTTP/1.1" 404
.......

Comment: @user3551959 Can you post both `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` lines in your `settings.py`?

Comment: I have
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/' `
`MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/' `

Comment: What do you see when you view the HTML source on your browser?